# Lottie AnimationView on Background ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've install Lottie on my Xcode project for my iOS app and i want make a full screen lottie animation with uibuttons.
It's ok for the animation, but my buttons not appear when my animation is running.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szAXE.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cigul.png)
Any ideas for make my button visible on front of animation ? 
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are adding the view of the animation on top of the button.
You can try to use `view.bringSubviewToFront(yourButton)` right after adding the animation view

Comment: Thank you so much wootage, I don't know who have downvote your answer but you have save me ! Thank you !!

Comment: glad I helped :)

Comment: Yes you have solved my problem thank you so much :D